# Volkswagen T Roc, remove gear knob

Tags: vw, gear-stick

I can't remove the knob. The plastic fins block the sliding and I don't have a "technique" suitable to do it. Tips?

[image]

Comment: I'm really not sure what part I'm looking at here?

Comment: Is that the gear shift knob removed from the vehicle?  Can you give us the big picture?  What are you trying to do?  What’s the goal here?

Comment: Remove the cuff knob